# On-demand function sharing

Tags: python

I need to convert from strings to the code named references. The only currently known option is a script that makes a script, and I was thinking it could be inline like `exec`.

```
class finder:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
  def isin(self, what):
    return what in self.parent
  def find(self, what):
    if self.isin(what): return self.parent.__dict__[what.__name__]
    else: return __import__("pull").__dict__["downloader"](self.parent.hosts).download(what)
  def put(self, what):
    f = self.find(what)
    self.parent.__dict__[f.__name__] = f

from sock import Socket
from unpack import unpacker
```

...

```
class downloader:
  def __init__(self, hosts):
    self.hosts = hosts
  def download(name):
    for host in hosts:
      pack = unpacker()
      s = Socket(host[0], host[1])
      s.send("get " + name)
      f = pack.unpack(s)
      if f is not None: return f
```

Comment: You are going to need to post some code.

Comment: I just don't get it. May someone explain?

Comment: @Sean Pedersen: Please provide (non-working) sample code that shows what you're trying to do?  Also, this sounds like `eval("SomeClassName")`.  Is it?

Comment: @Sean Pedersen: Where's the "strings to the code named references"?  What problem do you have?  That looks fine as it is.  Please be **specific**.  We can't guess and we can't read your mind.

Comment: @ Lott, please see the edit for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think what you're looking for is the ability to find the symbol for a method or attribute based on a string that is determined at runtime. If that's the case, I would pursue a different approach than a strategy based around `exec` or `eval` which have problems, like potential python injection attacks and tricky debugging...

In python **everything** is an object, including modules, classes and methods. How this helps you is that a module, let's call it `spam` may have a method, let's call it `eggs` you can access the `eggs` method by it's name like this:

```
spam.__dict__['eggs']
```

Now you may be asking "But how do I find the `spam` module by it's name?" This can done by importing the module by name using `__import__`:

```
spam = __import__('spam')
```

So, to call the `eggs` method with no arguments:

```
s = __import__('spam')
e = s.__dict__['eggs']
e()
```

Comment: @ Hoons, Excellent! Now on to the block list.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval`

```
>>> a = 'hi'

>>> b = 'a'

>>> eval(b)

'hi'
```